# Which has higher performance java or javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, opengl

Since now javascript gets compiled to machine code by browsers.  I was wondering which programming language gets better performance between java and javascript.  I'm thinking of writing a 3d browser FPS or MMO and am trying to decide between the two.

Also what are thoughts on compatibility?  It seems like with java and opengl I could reach a larger audience than using javascript and webgl since support hasn't been announced by IE.

Comment: java =/= javascript

Comment: which has higher performance snowmobile or scuba tank?

Comment: `I'm thinking of writing a 3d browser FPS or MMO` Better think of your **coding performance** then, since this is a gigantic task for one human being alone...

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Comment: "Since now javascript gets compiled to machine code by browsers." - Where did you hear this?

Comment: @suncliffe snowmobile if it is being driven by a polar bear. Things get hairy though when you're comparing it against a shark with a frickin' laser beam on its head that has a scuba tank on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Benoit says, this is a difficult question:

- Comparing (primarily) client-side and server-side languages is comparing apples and oranges.
- Different languages perform better / worse depending on the application / task.
- You can only benchmark language *implementations* not languages.

Having said that, here are a couple links to the "Computer Language Benchmarks Games" comparing Java and Javascript implementations:

- [JavaScript TraceMonkey vs Java 6 -Xint](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/compare.php?lang=tracemonkey)
- [JavaScript V8 vs Java 6 -Xint](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/javascript.php)

Note that these are comparing Javascript with *interpreted* Java.  You can fiddle around with the settings to get comparisons with (for example) server-mode Java.

Comment: Click the menu button for JavaScript V8 :: Java -server http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/compare.php?lang=v8&lang2=java Straight from the homepage for multicore Java -Xint :: Java -server  http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/compare.php?lang=javaxint

Comment: @igouy - So really, the best Javascript implementation is significant slower except for one regex-centric benchmark.

Comment: Whether it's "significantly slower" is something that people will quarrel about. Those measurements show those command line programs were that much slower when measured in that way, that's all. Maybe ignore the outliers and just look at the box plot http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php?v8=on&java=on&calc=chart

Comment: Client-server logic has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @vbence - The `-client` and `-server` switches on the Java command have nothing to do with "client-server logic".  They are tuning switches that can affect the *performance* of a JVM.

Comment: Stephen, my problem is not with the command line switches. I think the answer is fundamentally wrong in the following: "Comparing (primarily) client-side and server-side languages". Java is not more server-side than C++. Also: OP wanted to run the code inside the browser. A clear comparison can be made between an applet and a browser-based JS application.

Comment: @vbence - Javascript and Java can both be executed on the client side (e.g. in a browser).   Javascript and Java can both be executed server side (e.g. in an web server).  The performance comparison is *meaningful* ... though there is insufficient detail in the Question to know whether he is asking about client-side vs client-side or client-side vs server-side ... or both.

Answer (score 5):

As an avid FPS gamer, here's my biased two cents:

If you're going to write a 3D FPS, follow [QuakeLive](http://www.quakelive.com/)'s example and create a browser extension that uses compiled code.

In FPS games, every extra frame and every few millisecond counts. So, a cross-browser solution like Flash, Silverlight, Java etc. may not cut it.

It's a different story if you're writing a turn-based game or a MMORPG where latency or low frame rates don't necessarily matter.

Comment: Here's your upvote. @vlad003 : See also google earth and Bing! maps plug-ins.

Answer (score 4):

It is very difficult to give you a response. Java and Javascript are totally different languages :

- Javascript is executed by your browser: performance depends of you browser javascript engine
- Java (if executed on the client machine, by JNLP for example), run in a JVM environment: performance depends of your JVM

So there is no absolute response to your question.

Theses two languages have also very different functionnalities that can't be compared...

Comment: I'd also add that accessing local resources from JavaScript is almost impossible - and rightly so.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Starting with Java 6, you can actually embed other languages in it, and out of the box, it supports ECMAScript (JavaScript). It could be viable to implement part of a program in one language and part in another. Reference: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/

Comment: Does it need to be that difficult to give a response? When JavaScript performance depends on the particular browser JavaScript engine and Java performance depends on which JVM, can we simply ask how the best JavaScript performance compares to the best Java performance? How does the most widely available JavaScript performance compare to the most widely available Java performance?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, JavaScript's performance has greatly improved since the emphasis on scripting speed in Browser Wars 2.0; Java has evolved less radically. Directly comparing such fundamentally different languages isn't really practical, though. And to be honest I don't think performance of the core language is usually going to be your main problem if you're doing something as ambitious as a 3D game in the browser.

To add another option, today you would typically do this Flash using one of the 3D libraries.

Java is what you'd use yesterday (its desktop/applet acceptance is on the wane IMO); WebGL is, hopefully, what we'll be using tomorrow. All three are currently very annoying to write 3D apps with. Get a bunch of practice writing some 2D games before going anywhere near 3D in the browser!

Bonus option for if you don't mind arbitrary closed plugins: [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

Bonus option for if you're insane: JavaScript, doing the rendering itself, [to a `<canvas>`](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/wolf/).

Comment: I thought about this.  I looked into ray tracing and different lighting techniques but it seems like a lot of work, and although IE9 will support canvas there is still IE8, 7, and 6 to worry about.  I'm not sure I like the idea of not having hardware support for 3D rendering.  All these compatibility issues have kind of led me to leans toward Java.  I wasn't aware flash did 3D rendering though so I'll have to check that out.

Comment: You can't practically ray-trace in real time. The Wolfenstein example is ray-casting (ray-tracing on only one axis), which is more practical but still slow for anything but a tiny viewport, and limits you to rendering straight 90-degree walls and floors. Incidentally, another plugin option you can look at is Silverlight. But yeah, this fragmentation of partial support amongst unpopular plugins is why you don't really see 3D browser games today.

Comment: **Unity** always had an enourmous price tag attached, now I see [it claims to have gone free](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses) (with really pricy "pro" versions having pretty advanced features)

One very good thing about it though, is it now supports **iPhone** and **Wii**, too.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of detail you pretend from it, Java *could* cut it or not.

Take a look at **[Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/)**, a contemporary example of a **Java 3d multiuser environment** (alas, a very *blocky* one)

An yes, Javascript won't be able to give you any sensible 3D experience until [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) (or what will take its place in the final HTML5 revision) takes afoot.

But until then I found out you may give a look into **Google's [O3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O3D)**, an higher level interface to  Javascript 3D that is available *now* as an installable plugin (for IE too) and has vague promises of being available *later* as a **pure Javascript** implementation, *built over WebGL*

Anyway, in general: Java on the browser is declining in usage, (Minecraft being an awkward exception) while HTML5 is the new g*dam buzzword.

Comment: I also have to add that java applets are now increasingly becoming a **security scapegoat**, and with reason. More and more (oracle|sun)'s java implementation vulnerabilities are exploited each day by more and more rogue sites. Updating java is a massive task for sys admins, and java applets become less and less useful. Many simple disable the plugin and get done with it. After the third update in a month I disabled it too, and for good.

Answer (score -1):

For browser-based games, I don't think you should be using either. Flash is the way to go.

Also, 3D games, even simple ones, are a pretty heavy-duty task. I suspect you don't know what you're getting into, but there's only one way to find out.

Comment: I've hardly seen any 3D flash games. I knew full-blown Shockwave was the one plugin capable of 3d, while (Shockwave) Flash focused on 2D. I know a lot has changed, and now flash have as many APIs as one can imagine, but I still have to see one full-3d game made in flash. Do you know of one? Can you share it?